# how to prove this is a matroid in greedy solving?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Suppose we have a finite set called `P` and we have partitioned it into separate subsets

```
p1, p2, ... pj
```

we define `q` as all subsets `S` which at most have one member of each `pi`. so

```
q = { s:|intersect(s,pi)| <= 1, for i = 1...j }
```

prove that `(P,q)` is a matroid when its independent sets are `q`.

Comment: It helps if you write a bit more explaining your thinking. It seems like all you've done is written a title and pasted an algorithms homework question.

Comment: its easy just use two properties of matroid...it has a straight prove

Comment: @compass i have solved it before i just ask it here.The solution is this:
1.P is finite as stated in qusetion
2.q has inheritance because when we choose B all of its subset still has at most one member of pi
3.q has substitution property as when we have |A| < |B| then B has some memebers of Pi that are not in A so we can add them to A and still it has at most one member of Pi

Comment: @amirveyseh if you have solved it...post your answer and accept it! (for future readers)

Answer (score 0):

1.P is finite as stated in qusetion 2.q has inheritance because when we choose B all of its subset still has at most one member of pi 3.q has substitution property as when we have |A| < |B| then B has some memebers of Pi that are not in A so we can add them to A and still it has at most one member of Pi